# How do i delete a record from 2 table which have relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

As in Image , I want to Delete a record or row from the Profile and Login tables Where the Profile table  have relationship to Login By Id in the Profile table and Profileid in the Login table. 
[image]
I use this query :

```
DELETE      Profile.Id , Profile.Lastname, Profile.Name, Profile.Phone, Profile.Countryid,      Profile.Email, Profile.[Address], Profile.Typeid, Profile.[Status], Profile.Regdate, 
                     Login.[Password] Login.Username, Login.Id AS Loginid, Login.Profileid
FROM            Login INNER JOIN Profile ON Login.Profileid = Profile.Id

WHERE        Profile.Id = 4
```

But when i run this query i get this error Microsoft Sql Server 2008:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Is that appropriate query to do this Delete job?
if not How do i do that? I mean How query should be?

Comment: Come on man. At least look up the syntax for the `DELETE` statement. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Answer (score 1):

why not do something like this,

```
delete from profile where profile_id = 4

delete from login where profile_id = 4
```

Although you might wanna have cascading options set, for your foreign keys. That way you will only have to delete entry from profile table, and all the rows will from other tables will be deleted automatically where profile id =4. (or whatever id you delete from profile table.)

Comment: I cant use cascading because my master said, and I should mentioned that i want use this query in my program using Asp.net and how do i use two separate query when i Click on A button?? .

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the syntax for [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx).

You also need two delete statements. One for each table.

```
delete from login where profileid = 4

delete from profile where id = 4
```

Comment: i want use this query in my program using Asp.net and how do i use two separate query when i Click on A button?? .

Comment: @rezaasgary - It should be perfectly OK to add both these lines in one execute statement.

Comment: When i do that like this : http://uploadnow.org/image/334187-Capture.jpeg I got this error : http://uploadnow.org/image/334188-Capture2.jpeg which means i have to Delete Senduserid from Messages is that right ?? if yes on the other hands i have to DELETE all the Records From all tables which are related to Profile table,Right???

Comment: @rezaasgary - Before you can delete the profile you have to remove all references to that profile from all other tables. That can be done either by deleting the rows in the other tables or you can specify a different profile or you can update the profileid to null (if that is allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Login  WHERE Profile.Id = 4  --fist execute delete from child with FK

DELETE FROM Profile WHERE Profile.Id = 4    -- then execute delete from parent PK
```

First delete records from your Login Table which contain [FK]Profile.Id = 4.

Then If there is no [FK]Profile.Id = 4 exist on Login Table  then you can now delete it on Profile Table [PK]Profile.Id = 4.

Regards